# Add conditions on frequency of each value to expand grid in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, combinations

I want to create a table of available combination using colours

```
library(tidyr)

#give available colour combo
colour= c("BK", "CS", "DB","DG","LB","LG","MV","OR","RD","WT","YL","ID","EMPTY")

combo = expand.grid(colour, colour,colour, colour)
#function "colnames" to change column names
colnames(combo) <- c('A','B','C','D')
```

What I want is a condition on the 2 last colours "**ID**" and "**EMPTY**"
The condition is that for each combination, so for each line they are aloud to be in only 1 column (A,B,C or D) at a time. So their frequency is 0.25. But they also need to be in at least 1 column.

Comment: So am I correct that you want only rows that have either 'ID' or 'EMPTY' but not both?

Comment: can you give an example of the valid row?

Comment: @George, No, each row must have 'ID' and 'EMPTY' with all available combinations with the colour list above. "BK ID EMPTY RD" is a valid row for example.

Answer (score 0):

If order does not matter:

```
library(combinat)
library(data.table) # for rbindlist

colour <- c("BK", "CS", "DB","DG","LB","LG","MV","OR","RD","WT","YL")
combo <- setnames(as.data.table(t(combn(colour, 2))), c("A", "B"))[, c("C", "D") := .("ID","EMPTY")]
head(combo)
#>     A  B  C     D
#> 1: BK CS ID EMPTY
#> 2: BK DB ID EMPTY
#> 3: BK DG ID EMPTY
#> 4: BK LB ID EMPTY
#> 5: BK LG ID EMPTY
#> 6: BK MV ID EMPTY
```

If order does matter, simply permute the columns of `combo`:

```
combo <- rbindlist(lapply(permn(4), function(x) combo[, ..x]), FALSE)
```